# Assign tags above 9 to message in Thunderbird

Tags: javascript, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Are there any commands or functions in Thunderbird that assigns a specific tag to a message? I have more than nine tags, so I need more shortcuts.

I have installed the tbkeys add-on: https://github.com/wshanks/tbkeys
I'm able to assign commands and functions like func:AddTag and cmd:cmd_addTag, but those adds a brand new tag. I would like to use one of the tags I've already defined.

I would think that assigning a tag to a message is something needed much more often than adding a new tag, so it's strange that I can't find a way of doing it. I looked through the list here: https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/tip/mail/base/content/mainCommandSet.inc.xhtml
But the mailTagMenuItems only has addTag, mangeTags and removeTags.

Are there nothing like AssignTag('NameOfTag')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ToggleMessageTag(key, addKey)](https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/tip/mail/base/content/mailWindowOverlay.js#l1157) function. This function will add or remove a tag for the selected messages.

Each tag has a key associated with it. The key is derived from the tag, certain characters are [replaced by underscores](https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/tip/mailnews/base/src/nsMsgTagService.cpp#l212) and then [Modified UTF-7 encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501.html#section-5.1.3) [is used](https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/tip/mailnews/base/src/nsMsgTagService.cpp#l214).

In simple cases, like "mytag", the key and the tag can be the same. But add a space and the tag ("my tag") will be different from the key ("my_tag").

[The tag service](https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/tip/mailnews/base/src/nsMsgTagService.cpp) is responsible for tag management. Using this interface you can [add a new tag](https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/tip/mailnews/base/src/nsMsgTagService.cpp#l203) or [get a key](https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/tip/mailnews/base/src/nsMsgTagService.cpp#l127) for a tag. In JavaScript you can use MailServices.tags from [MailServices.jsm](https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/tip/mailnews/base/src/MailServices.jsm) to access the tag service.

To assign a "my tag" to selected messages you can use the following code:

```
ToggleMessageTag(MailServices.tags.getKeyForTag('my tag'), true);
```

Depending on the second argument, the tag will be either added (true) or removed (false). For the tbkeys, you will need to use ["Eval commands"](https://github.com/wshanks/tbkeys#command-syntax).

A more far-sighted way to change message tags is to use [Thunderbird WebExtension API](https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-ons/about-add-ons). You can use [messages API](https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/latest/messages.html) to [update](https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/latest/messages.html#update-messageid-newproperties) [tags](https://webextension-api.thunderbird.net/en/latest/messages.html#messagetag).

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help and very teachable explanation with links. I really appreciate it! Now I have added several new shortcuts like "ctrl+2": "window.ToggleMessageTag(window.MailServices.tags.getKeyForTag('chaplaincy'), true);",

(I'm using full version of tbkeys, not light-version. )

Comment: I'm happy to help. And you made a good point about using a [window variable](https://github.com/wshanks/tbkeys/blob/39397452d221cca635eff04b635b36a352caae20/addon/implementation.js#L99) for [tbkeys](https://github.com/wshanks/tbkeys#tbkeys-and-tbkeys-lite). The point is that the code is executed using the [Experiments API](https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-ons/mailextensions/experiments) and the stuff we need are not in the scope, but we can access that through the [window variable](https://github.com/wshanks/tbkeys/blob/39397452d221cca635eff04b635b36a352caae20/addon/implementation.js#L99)